# Sidedrawer in Telerik's UI for Nativescript is not working on Angular2 project

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

**Hi there people!**

I'm experimenting an issue with [this package](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/introduction) and my Nativescript application with Angular2 and Typescript.

When I run the application and I tap the button that should call my sidedrawer, I get the next Unhandled error:

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onClick failed

Error: Error in app.component.html:26:35 caused by: self.context.openDrawer is not a function
```

The full error log will be at the end of the post, but this is the part of the log I consider relevant to fix this issue.

My `main.ts` has the next imports and declarations:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import drawerModule = require("nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer");
import { SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
imports: [NativeScriptModule],
})
```

My `app.component.html` has the button that executes the problematic function:

```
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

This is my `AppComponent` class inside my `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
public counter: number = 16;

public get message(): string {
    if (this.counter > 0) {
        return this.counter + " taps left";
    } else {
        return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
    }
}

public onTap() {
    this.counter--;
}

@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
private drawer: SideDrawerType;

public openDrawer() {
    this.drawer.showDrawer();
}
}
```

In this case, the tag **Button** has a **(tap)** property that executes **openDrawer()**, a function from the sidedrawer directives.

This is the documentation I was following in the matter:

- [Telerik UI](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/getting-started)
- [Telerik UI & Angular](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/getting-started)
- [Angular Sidedrawer by Telerik UI](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started)

This is the full error log in case I forgot to mention something else:

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onClick failed

Error: Error in app.component.html:26:35 caused by: self.context.openDrawer is not a function
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js, line: 9668, column: 20

StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 9668, column: 21
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 9681, column: 27
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js', line: 221, column: 26
Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js', line: 190, column: 28
Frame: function:'NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 6220, column: 41
Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js', line: 189, column: 34
Frame: function:'Zone.run', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js', line: 83, column: 43
Frame: function:'NgZoneImpl.runInner', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 6247, column: 75
Frame: function:'NgZone.run', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js', line: 6477, column: 70
Frame: function:'zonedCallback', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js', line: 220, column: 24
Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 149, column: 23
Frame: function:'Observable._emit', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 168, column: 18
Frame: function:'_android.setOnClickListener.android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.nbapp/files/app/tns_modules/ui/button/button.js', line: 33, column: 32


at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:865)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:730)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:716)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:697)
at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:687)
at com.tns.gen.android.view.View_OnClickListener.onClick(android.view.View$OnClickListener.java)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

---

**Thanks a lot in advance, I hope you could help me and please, please, tell me if you need me to provide some additional information on the issue.**

Comment: Perhaps you have some issues while defining the `openDrawer` method inside the AppComponent class. However to be able to review your problem you should also share your code for you `AppComponent` class. In the meantime you could review my sample project here - https://github.com/tsonevn/NGSideDrawer , where has been used `SideDrawer` component. For Further help you could also use the  `nativescript-telerik-ui` sample app - https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular .

Comment: Your comment provided me a lot of insight in the matter. Thanks for that, your example was pretty useful also.
I'll provide my `AppComponent` class to the main thread so you can review it.

Comment: When I reviewed the given code I  noticed that you did not initialize the  `drawer ` property in your code. Try to initialize it inside the `ngAfterViewInit` as it has been shown here -https://github.com/tsonevn/NGSideDrawer/blob/master/app/app.component.ts#L17 and verify whether you will have the same problem.

Comment: Now it is working! =D
Thank you!